# Non-admin user cannot access scanner

Tags: catalina, permission, user-account, scanning

I have a Brother scanner / printer connected via USB to a MacBook Pro. I'm using a plain user account that does not have admin rights for daily work.

Scanning works nicely for an admin user but *not* for a non-admin user. Printing works for both users.

Trying to access the scanner from the system settings yields "Waiting for scanner" at first and after about 30secs the message "Failed to open a connection to the device (-21345)" for the non-admin user.

OS version is 10.15.7 (Catalina).

This looks like a permission issue to me, I'm happy to hear about ideas on how to dig into or fix this.

id -a for non-admin-user:

```
uid=501(non-admin-user) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),399(com.apple.access_ssh),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),98(_lpadmin),100(_lpoperator)
```

id -a for admin-user:

```
uid=502(admin-user) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),702(com.apple.sharepoint.group.2),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),400(com.apple.access_remote_ae)
```

Comment: Can you open Terminal, run `id -a ADMINUSER; id -a STDUSER` (with the short user name) and add the result to the question?

Comment: yep, pls find the updated question above.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I was hoping that the standard users misses an obvious group there, but no luck.

Comment: Some apps ask at installation time if the software is to be used solely by the user running the installation software, or for _all users_ of the computer. Perhaps this question was asked at the first installation of the Brother software and the first option was chosen. If possible, see if the Brother software can be completely uninstalled (it may have an Uninstaller app available) and try reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback so far.

I'm only using default OS X drivers, the stuff OS X fetches when it detects the device. No additional Brother software was installed.

I'm wondering if there's an e.g. queue-/device-/wuteva-file that the non-admin-user needs read access to.